# Algebra - roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\sqrt[3]{5+x} + \sqrt[3]{5-x} = 2*\sqrt[3]{5}$

Hi everyone! I've tried solving it but it's not working.
Here what I've tried: [image: sol]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead. You have $(5+x)^{1/3}+(5-x)^{1/3} = 2(5^{1/3})$.

So, $2[(5+x)(5-x)]^{1/3}\color{blue}{(5^{1/3})} = 2[25-x^2]^{1/3}5^{1/3} = 10 \Rightarrow \color{green}{(25-x^2)(5) = 5^3}$

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: @Ak19 The substitution $\sqrt[3]{5+x}+\sqrt[3]{5-x}=2\sqrt[3]5$ it's not an equivalent transformation in the general. You need to check that $0$ is a root of the equation. For example, your method gives a wrong solution for the following equation. $\sqrt[3]{x+1}+1=\sqrt[3]{2x-1}.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2$$ and the equality $$\sqrt[3]{5+x}=\sqrt[3]{5-x}=-2\sqrt[3]5$$ is impossible, our equation is equivalent to
$$5+x+5-x-40+3\cdot2\sqrt[3]{5(5+x)(5-x)}=0$$ or
$$25-x^2=25$$ or $$x=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just another way, due to symmetry it is enough to consider non-negative $x$, and as $x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ is concave, by Jensen's inequality
$$\sqrt[3]{5+x} + \sqrt[3]{5-x} \leqslant 2\sqrt[3]5$$

with equality iff $5+x=5-x \implies x = 0$